# Python Tkinter Double Scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to display a bunch of very long labels with a scrollbar frame.

For some reason, I need to set the width and height of each label to a fixed value.

But in that case, when the `label text` exceeds the `label width` and `label height` some portion of label is not displayed.

So, I want to add another scrollbar for each label that has longer label text than the label width and height. Here is what I have tried:

```
from Tkinter import*
def myfunction(event):
        canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"),width=300,height=400)
root=Tk()
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (500, 500, 5, 5))

data1="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.place(x=20,y=20)
canvas1=Canvas(frame1)
frame2=Frame(canvas1,bg='white',relief=GROOVE,bd=0,width=1230,height=400)
scrollbar1=Scrollbar(frame1,orient="vertical",command=canvas1.yview)
canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar1.set)
scrollbar1.pack(side="right",fill="y")
canvas1.pack(side="left")
canvas1.create_window((0,0),window=frame2,anchor='nw')
frame2.bind("<Configure>",myfunction)

for i in range(10):
    Label(frame2,text=data1,width=30,height=4,bg='white',relief=GROOVE,bd=1,wraplength=200,anchor=NW,justify=LEFT).grid(row=i,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Currently, I have a bunch of labels displayed using grid method on the canvas that has a scrollbar attached. As you can see, a potion of my data "aaaa..." is not displayed. Is there anyway I can add a scrollbar to each label boxes? I don't want to change the size of label box.

Or should I use `Text box` instead of labels?

**--EDIT--**

This is what I have tried:

```
from Tkinter import*
def myfunction(event):
        canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"),width=400,height=200)
def myfunctionx(event):
        canvas1x.configure(scrollregion=canvas1x.bbox("all"),width=100,height=50)
root=Tk()
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (500, 500, 5, 5))

data1="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.place(x=20,y=20)
canvas1=Canvas(frame1)
frame2=Frame(canvas1,bg='white',relief=GROOVE,bd=0,width=1230,height=400)
scrollbar1=Scrollbar(frame1,orient="vertical",command=canvas1.yview)
canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar1.set)
scrollbar1.pack(side="right",fill="y")
canvas1.pack(side="left")
canvas1.create_window((0,0),window=frame2,anchor='nw')
frame2.bind("<Configure>",myfunction)

frame1x=Frame(frame1,bg='green',width=100,height=50,bd=1,relief=GROOVE)
frame1x.place(x=10,y=20)
canvas1x=Canvas(frame1x,bg='yellow',relief=GROOVE,bd=0,width=100,height=50)
frame2x=Frame(canvas1x,bg='white',relief=GROOVE,bd=0,width=100,height=50)
scrollbar1x=Scrollbar(frame1x,orient="vertical",command=canvas1x.yview)
canvas1x.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar1x.set)
scrollbar1x.pack(side="right",fill="y")
canvas1x.pack(side="left")
canvas1x.create_window((0,0),window=frame2x,anchor='nw')
frame2x.bind("<Configure>",myfunctionx)

for i in range(10):
        Label(frame2x,text=data1,width=20,height=4,bg='white',relief=GROOVE,bd=1,wraplength=200,anchor=NW,justify=LEFT).grid(row=i,column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

But instead of adding scrollbar to each label, it puts all labels into 1 scrollbar. Is there any way I can have 1 scrollbar for each label box? (Assuming I will use looping to create several label boxes.)

Comment: Of the [scrollable widgets](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm) provided by Tkinter, I'd suggest making each of your labels a `Listbox`. However those don't support a `wraplength` option, so potentially you'd need to attach both a horizontal and vertical scrollbar to each one.

Comment: Another possibility might be a scrollable [`LabelFrame`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113937/how-do-you-create-a-labelframe-with-a-scrollbar-in-tkinter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a scrollbar to scroll a label.

If you need text that is scrollable, use an Entry or Text widget.

Comment: Thanks! managed to get it working by using Text widget (state=DISABLED).